# Making richfaces select component accessible for JAWS using ARIA

Tags: combobox, richfaces, selectonemenu, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

i am trying to make the rich:select component (with manual input enabled) from richfaces accessible for handicapped users with WAI-ARIA attributes. I am adding the Attributes directly in the SelectRenderer.java Class.
I am using:

- IE9 (this one is the browser we HAVE to use)
- RichFaces 4: especially rich:select with enabled Manual Input
- JAWS 15.0

The Current HTML structure of the rendered rich:select looks like this (contains my changes already):

```
<div id="registration:persondata:gender" class="rf-sel" aria-labelledby="registration:persondata:genderLabel" role="combobox">
    <span class="rf-sel-cntr">
        <input id="registration:persondata:genderselValue" type="hidden" name="registration:persondata:gender" value="">
        <input id="registration:persondata:genderInput" class="rf-sel-inp rf-sel-dflt-lbl" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).select();" name="registration:persondata:genderInput" aria-activedescendant="registration:persondata:genderItem0" aria-owns="registration:persondata:genderItems" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" title="" customtitle="true">
        <span id="registration:persondata:genderButton" class="rf-sel-btn">
            <span class="rf-sel-btn-arrow"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <div id="registration:persondata:genderList" class="rf-sel-lst-cord">
        <div class="rf-sel-shdw">
            <div class="rf-sel-shdw-t"></div>
            <div class="rf-sel-shdw-l"></div>
            <div class="rf-sel-shdw-r"></div>
            <div class="rf-sel-shdw-b"></div>
            <div class="rf-sel-lst-dcrtn">
                <div class="rf-sel-lst-scrl" style="min-height: 20px; width: auto; min-width: 307px;">
                    <div id="registration:persondata:genderItems" role="listbox">
                        <div id="registration:persondata:genderItem0" class="rf-sel-opt" title="Empty Entry" role="option"> </div>
                        <div id="registration:persondata:genderItem1" class="rf-sel-opt" title="male" role="option">m</div>
                        <div id="registration:persondata:genderItem2" class="rf-sel-opt" title="Undescribed" role="option">u</div>
                        <div id="registration:persondata:genderItem3" class="rf-sel-opt" title="Female" role="option">f</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following Changes and Attributes i have already implemented:

- Whenever the ItemsList popups the invisible list of HTML items will
  become visible and be moved on the end of the HTML document. I
  removed the moving of this Element to the bottom, so now it stays at the same place
  like in the above structure (everything else works still fine)
- The first DIV Container which contains the Input, the Button and the
  Items-Container received role"combobox" and aria-labelledby="IDofLabel" attribute

The Input received the following Changes:

- aria-activedescendant="IDofRandomItem": Notice if i ommit this Attribute, i wont get any response from JAWS beside "this is an Input". With this line (and a valid Item ID as a value) i get at least a response which says "this a select menu", which works fine. But this should be the combobox response!
- aria-owns="Id of the Element containing the items as Children"
- aria-autocomplete="list" : since i want this one to be recognized as a ComboBox.

The Element containing the Items aswell as the items have the following changes:

- role="listbox" The Element containing the items is referenced as a listbox
- role="option" Every Item received this role to be recognized as an actual Item.

As already said I do get the "select menu" response, but not the "combobox, select with arrow keys, or type" response which i am aiming for. 
BTW: when i add tabindex="0" to the first DIV which contains the combox role i DO get the desired response, BUT it focuses the whole container NOT the input. So if i press tab at this stage the focus goes into my actual Input reading it as input. If i try to add the combobox role to the Input-Element instead JAWS still recognizes this is a selectmenu.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the `role=combobox` be on the input?

Comment: I could find both variants while researching: 1. putting the role=combobox on the surrounding container, which contains the Input, Button and the Container with the Elements. 2. putting the role=combobox on the input. I have tried both variants and had the exact same result: my combobox was recognized as a SelectMenu, but not as a combobox

Comment: Best practice from WAI-ARIA explains two patterns to make a combobox accessible: either have the combobox role on a wrapping container or directly on the input with following button and list elements. I think the major problem here is, that the items container is not on the same level as the input and button is. Another thing i found is, that my code works perfectly fine while using firefox. Too bad we have the order to develop for the IE. I do not know why IE seems to interpret the same code in a different way...